# .htaccess redirect to another folder but keep the original domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

First,

my `'example.com'` domain is linked to `'/home/defaultfolder/'` folder.

I want to redirect

```
example.com , www.example.com
```

to

`/home/somefolder/example/` , not `/home/defaultfolder/` folder

by using .htaccess. (both are inside the DocumentRoot directory)

also, subdomains like

```
a.example.com
```

to

```
/somefolder/example/a/
```

but keeps the 'example.com' domain.

I have tried some examples on the web, but nothing could have done it.

How can I write the .htaccess to do so? Thank you.

Of course, I cannot change server settings(like alias virtual hosts..) and that's why I am trying to do it by modifying the file.

---

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /somefolder/example/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$   
RewriteRule !^/somefolder/example/ /somefolder/example/1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/?(?:www\.)?example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /somefolder/example/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

and some others..

Comment: Show us your attempts so that we may give you suggestions.

Comment: @anubhava then if the path is inside the DocumentRoot? How can I manage it?

Comment: However note that if `/home/defaultfolder/` is your site root then `/home/somefolder/` is considered outside `DocumentRoot`. Only `/home/defaultfolder/somefolder/` can be considered within `DocumentRoot` path.

Comment: @anubhava /home/ as the DocumentRoot folder. Can access to both folder.

Comment: oh you mentioned `/home/defaultfolder/` in question. Is site root of  `example.com` set to `/home/` or `/home/defaultfolder/`? In your browser can you open `http://example.com/somefolder/example/` and see the correct page ?

Comment: @anubhava yes. it's just for convenience. Anyone can access to http://example.com/somefolder/example and http://example.com/defaultfolder . sorry for not specifying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way in `/home/.htaccess` (site root):

```
RewriteEngine On

# handle example.com
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* somefolder/%1/$0 [L]

# handle any sub.example.com
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.(example)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* somefolder/%2/%1/$0 [L]
```

Comment: almost perfect! only that when I try to access the subdomain website, "The requested URL /somefolder/subname./ was not found on this server." shows. The 'period . ' matters. Tried to modify, but couldn't.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in 2nd rule. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify the server setting, make the domain root folder to what you want.

Comment: I have no auth to modify the server side setting

Comment: You are using cPanel? Or xampp etc?

Comment: my hosting provider didn't license those features.